# whatsapp group by twillio

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm trying to create a WhatsApp group between a Twilio number and two or more users their number will get using a request using java, can Twilio or twiML support this and how?

I've searched but all I found was for just one number.

Answer (score 0):

Group messaging is currently not supported on Twilio WhatsApp.

[Can I send messages to WhatsApp groups or manage groups?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs)

Currently, our API does not support messaging with or managing WhatsApp groups. We expect to add support for groups in the future.

You can look at [Twilio Conversations](https://www.twilio.com/conversations) which supports WhatsApp as one of a few different channels, and allows you to add multiple participants to a conversation, and share content with all participants in that conversation.